# Local Newspaper article, homework, on "Of Mice and Men" book

Tags: journalism

I have been set homework from my English teacher to answer this question in the "Of Mice and Men" book by John Steinbeck.

---

Imagine that you are a reporter for the local newspaper in Soledad where Carlson has taken Curley to have his broken hand treated, following his fight with Lennie. You manage to get Curley to tell you the real reason of how his hand got smashed.

Using ICT if possible, write an article on the incident based on your interviews with Curley and Carlson. Explain:

- how the fight started
- who was to blame
- what Curley's and Carlson's impressions are of Lennie
- what, if any, action should be taken against him.

---

I have read this part of the book and have watched the whole movie in class, so I understand the situation, but need help on writing as a reporter, as I have not written a newspaper article before and am not sure how to.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Writers.  We can't tell you what to write, but a question about journalistic writing is fine.  Asking about journalism as a whole feels too broad, though; could you [edit] this to be a more-specific question?  For example, is your question about how to structure a news story?  Is it about sentence/paragraph structure?  About chronicling events sequentially versus by importance?  About speaking with a neutral voice?  All of these would be fine topics for questions (feel free to ask more than one).  I'm going to put this on hold temporarily; when you edit it we can re-open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best reporting is as simple as possible, factual and as clear as the events reported on. Limit yourself to 6th grade reading level. When reporting opinions of participants, use quotes. Your opinions should be kept out of the reporting. Since your teacher is also asking for opinion, I would turn in two articles, and make the second an editorial where you argue for your position. Further since you are working with fiction you do not need to limit your quotes to the book, but you can use what the characters would say to the questions you ask them.

Comment: This was very helpful! Thank you my good sir! (I hope I don't get told off for saying thanks :/)